# Null Pointer Exception in Spring MVC Project

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, nullpointerexception

I'm creating a form that contains the fields of a professor, this fields are id (long), nome(string), username (string), email(string) and curso_coord(curso), being that curso is a reference variable for a class course.

In the form, the username, name and email fields are entered for the user to fill in and the course is a select for the user to select the course if he / she is coordinator of that course or -1 if not

I try curso.get(0).getId() to solve the problem but it's not enough

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = { "/professor" })
public class ProfessorController {
    @Autowired
    ProfessorRepository pr;
    CursoRepository c;

    @GetMapping(value = "")
    @ResponseBody
    public ModelAndView professorInicio() {
        ModelAndView form = new ModelAndView("/form");
        form.addObject("professor", new Professor());
        List<Curso> curso = c.findAll();
        curso.get(0).getId();
        form.addObject("curso", curso);
        return form;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "")
    @ResponseBody
    public ModelAndView cadastraProfessor(@ModelAttribute ("professor") Professor professor){
        //Professor prof = new Professor();
        ModelAndView index = new ModelAndView("/index");
        professor.getUsername();
        professor.getEmail();
        professor.getNome();
        professor.getCursoCoord();
        pr.save(professor);

        return index;
    }

 ....
}

<form th:action="@{/professor}" th:object = "${professor}" method="POST">

            <div class = "form-group">
                <label for = "username">Username</label>
                <input type = "text" th:field = "*{username}" autofocus = "autofocus"/>
            </div>
            <div class = "form-group">
                    <label for = "nome">Nome</label>
                    <input type = "text" th:field = "*{nome}" autofocus = "autofocus"/>
            </div>
            <div class = "form-group">
                    <label for = "email">Email</label>
                    <input type = "hidden" name="email" value="">
                    <input type = "text" th:field = "*{email}" autofocus = "autofocus"/>
            </div>
            <div class = "form-group">
                <select th:field = "*{curso_coord}">
                    <option 
                    th:each = "c: ${cursos}"
                    th:value = "${c.id}">Cursos
                    </option>
                    <option value = -1> Não Coordenador
                    </option>
                </select>"
            </div>
            <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-success ">Salvar</button>
        </form>
```

> 2019-10-04 15:37:00.700 ERROR 17580 --- [nio-8081-exec-1]
>   c.p.p.controller.ErrorController         : Algum erro ocorreu!
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException: null
>           at com.planoensino.planoensino.controller.ProfessorController.professorInicio(ProfessorController.java:35)
>   ~[main/:na]
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_181]
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_181]
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
>           at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:877)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:783)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974)
>   [spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866)
>   [spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
>   [javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851)
>   [spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
>   [javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
>           at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>   [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
>   [spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
>   [spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
>   [spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>   [spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
>   [spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>   [spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
>   [spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>   [spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
>   [spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>   [spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
>   [spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>   [spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
>   [spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>   [spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
>   [spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>   [spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
>   [spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>   [spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
>   [spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   [spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>   [spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
>   [spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>   [spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
>   [spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   [spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>   [spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
>   [spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
>   [spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
>   [spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
>   [spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
>   [spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   [spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109)
>   [spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   [spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
>   [spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   [spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
>           at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:147)
>   [spring-session-core-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:81)
>   [spring-session-core-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
>   [spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   [spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
>           at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
>           at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
>           at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:800)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1471)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   [na:1.8.0_181]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   [na:1.8.0_181]
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_181]
>
> 2019-10-04 15:37:00.702  WARN 17580 --- [nio-8081-exec-1]
>   .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused
>   by Handler execution: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: It looks like member variable c is null on `List<Curso> curso = c.findAll();`  in  `professorInicio()` method, please look at your lines and at line number 35. using @Autowired over 'CursoRepository c;' may help as it looks like this object is not instantiated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to put `@Autowired` on `CursoRepository c`

Just modify the code by replacing the existing one :

```
@Autowired
CursoRepository c;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CursoRepository c;
```

is not a Spring managed bean, try

```
@Autowired
ProfessorRepository pr;

@Autowired
CursoRepository c;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is missing to add `@Autowired annotation` for `CursoRepository` that is the reason the null pointer exception.

```
@Autowired
CursoRepository c;
```